# Azure Data factory - Not able to retrieve JSON lookup activity out put, when JSON key is having space in it

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have JSON file with below structure

```
{
"AppId" : 1
"App Name" : "XYZ"
}
```

I am reading this JSON file using LOOKUP activity in azure data factory. And trying to assign lookup.output.firstrow to variable.

I am able to assign AppId to a variable from lookup output.

```
Lookup.output.firstrow.AppId
```

But I am not able to assign "App Name" to a variable

```
Lookup.output.firstrow.App Name
```

When I try to run in debug I get some syntax or runtime error

It is because of the space in **"App Name"**
If I change the JSON key to **"AppName"** then no issue.

Let me know if anyone is able retrieve value from key having space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are special characters in your JSON key, you can put it in square brackets and quote it .
Please try this:

```
Lookup.output.firstrow['App Name']
```

Comment: Is there any experssion available in adf to get the keys alone in an array ? here as per this json , i want the experssion output as ["AppId" , "App Name"]